# Asking for a x509 certificate's password from Windows-My store

Tags: c#, x509certificate2

I could get the certificates in Windows-My store with this code:

```
X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
store.Open(OpenFlags.IncludeArchived);

X509Certificate2Enumerator enumerator = store.Certificates.GetEnumerator();
// then I loop through the enumerator and store the certificates in a list
store.Close();
```

In my app, user selects a certificate and I have to ask for its password. If the password is correct, user can enter the app's options. I can do this with pfx or pkcs12 certificates from user's selected file:

```
X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2();

try
{
    cert.Import(File.ReadAllBytes(pathToMyPfxCert), "my password", X509KeyStorageFlags.DefaultKeySet);
}
catch (CryptographicException)
{
    //wrong password! :D
}
```

But I'm not sure if this is possible when selecting a certificate from Windows-My. When I exported the Windows-My certificates to a pfx file and imported them again with a wrong password I spected an CryptographicException screaming "The network password is invalid", but I got no exceptions as if I were entering the right password.

Please, also tell me if I'm using Windows-My certificates the wrong way or in a way they were not designed for (I'm a newbie in this x509 stuff).

**Edit: About @CryptoGuy comment:**

I agree: it is a little odd, because it is a little experimental: we want to know if Windows-My Store certificates can be used for login on a desktop app instead of signing a document.
My testing certificate is configured in such way that user is asked for the password to access the private key when signing a document:

[image: cert configured to ask for pk's pw]

The application I'm using to sign files and get this dialog is [XolidoSign](http://www.xolido.com/lang/productosxolidosign/xolidosignescritorio/).

I want to do the same in my app: ask for the certificate's password (or its private key's password) and check it to login into my app.

Comment: have you tried looking at any documentation and or finding examples online in regards to the `X509` stuff.. what have you tried in that regard..?

Comment: @MethodMan : yes, I tried. The sample codes I found ask for a password when the certificate comes from a file, not from Windows-My. And the documentation I found describes the certificate's format and standar.

Comment: @CryptoGuy I want to use these certificates for login purposes. User chooses a certificate from a listbox and writes the password in a textBox. If the password is correct, user can enter the application.

Comment: something is odd in this process. You should either use login/password or client certificate authentication process and should not combine them. If user has valid certificate to use within your application -- why you ever want to ask for password? If password is required, then you don't need to waste resources for certificates.

Comment: I agree with @CryptoGuy that you completely misuse the certificates.

Comment: the dialog you are referring is used for different purposes. It is called "Private key strong protection" and is used to protect the key from unauthorized use. It is not an authentication validation mechanism.

Comment: @CryptoGuy : "It is not an authentication validation mechanism" you made it all clear now, thanks!